# NextAuth Github Provider Error "client_id is required "

Tags: next.js, next.js13, next-auth

I'm using next auth for authentication.

My code for GithubProvider is -

```js
import GitHubProvider from "next-auth/providers/github";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";

export const options = {
  providers : [
    GitHubProvider({
      profile(profile) {
        console.log("Profile Github: ", profile);

        let userRole = "GitHub User";
        if (profile?.email == "raj.cs.psg@gmail.com") {
          userRole = "admin";
        }

        return {
          ...profile,
          role: userRole,
        };
      },
      clientId: process.env.GITHUB_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GITHUB_Secret,
    }),
    GoogleProvider({
      profile(profile) {
        console.log("Profile Google: ", profile);


        return {
          ...profile,
          id: profile.sub,
          role: userRole,
        };
      },
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_Secret,
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user}) {
      if(user) {
        token.role = user.role;
      }
      return token;
    },

    async session({session, token}) {
      if(session?.user) session.user.role = token.role;
      return session;
    }
  }
};
```

my .env.local file is -

```
Github_ID=<>
Github_Secret=<>
```

my complete project is in github [here](https://github.com/rajcspsg/next-auth-tutorial/tree/main).

When I run this app I get error -

```json
[next-auth][error][SIGNIN_OAUTH_ERROR] 
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#signin_oauth_error client_id is required {
  error: {
    message: 'client_id is required',
    stack: 'TypeError: client_id is required\n' +
      '    at new BaseClient (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/openid-client/lib/client.js:148:19)\n' +
      '    at new Client (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/openid-client/lib/client.js:1654:13)\n' +
      '    at openidClient (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/core/lib/oauth/client.js:23:20)\n' +
      '    at getAuthorizationUrl (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/core/lib/oauth/authorization-url.js:88:51)\n' +
      '    at Object.signin (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/core/routes/signin.js:21:66)\n' +
      '    at AuthHandler (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/core/index.js:259:49)\n' +
      '    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)\n' +
      '    at async NextAuthRouteHandler (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js:50:30)\n' +
      '    at async NextAuth._args$ (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js:85:24)\n' +
      '    at async /home/raju/Coding/auth/next-auth-tutorial/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:62499',
    name: 'TypeError'
  },
  providerId: 'github',
  message: 'client_id is required'
}
```

What is wrong with my code and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Env variables are Case Sensitive.

if you use this in .env

```
Github_ID=<>
Github_Secret=<>
```

Then you have to use this inside the code.

```
process.env.Github_ID
process.env.Github_Secret
```

Answer (score -2):

According to the error message, the client_id is required when configuring the GitHub OAuth provider. This means that the OAuth client ID for your GitHub app is not set up properly, or at all. I've set the client_id and client_secret in my .env.local file, but the actual environment variable names don't seem to match what I'm using in my code.

The environment variable names used in the code are GITHUB_ID and GITHUB_Secret. However, the .env.local file has Github_ID and Github_Secret. Environment variables are case sensitive and must match exactly.

Please follow these steps to resolve the issue:
In the .env.local file, change the environment variable names exactly as specified in your code. For example, you need to change Github_ID to GITHUB_ID and Github_Secret to GITHUB_Secret.

1. In the .env.local file, change the environment variable names exactly as specified in the code. For example, you need to change Github_ID to GITHUB_ID and Github_Secret to GITHUB_Secret.
2. Verify that environment variables are being referenced correctly in your code. For this, you need to check the clientId and clientSecret values ​​in your code.
3. Before restarting the server, check whether the environment variables have changed. Node.js does not update environment variables dynamically at runtime, so you must restart the server after making changes to the .env.local file.
4. If this still doesn't work, try checking the logs by temporarily adding code like console.log(process.env.GITHUB_ID) to make sure the environment variables are loaded correctly on your system. This will ensure that the actual environment variable values ​​are loaded.